# Maven 3: How to exclude generated sources from Xlint check?

Tags: java, maven, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

We only allow java source code without Xlint errors. However, when sources are generated by third party tools, this is not practical. Examples of generated sources in our use-case are: JFlex, JavaCC, JAXB and annotation processors.

So the question is: how to exclude the generated sources from the Xlint checks? (see current configuration below)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration combine.self="override">
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <!-- Since JDK1.3 javac ignores any optimization flags -->
        <optimize>true</optimize>
        <debug>false</debug>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- everything in target/generated-sources/** should be excluded from this check -->
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-rawtypes</arg>
          </compilerArgs>                     
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct configuration in the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin) to do that. The parameters passed are for the whole execution, so passing `-Xlint:all` would apply to all sources to compile.

The solution here is to compile it in two pass: first pass would compile the generated sources without any lint check, and the second pass would compile your project sources (that might depend on the generated classes). Again, the Compiler Plugin doesn't offer a way to specify a path to sources to compile: it compiles all of the sources of the current Maven project.

You have 2 solutions: use 2 executions of the Compiler Plugin with includes/excludes or split this in 2 modules.

#### Include/Exclude

The idea is to have 2 executions: one that would [`exclude`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#excludes) your main classes (and compile the generated ones), while the other execution would [`include`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#includes) them. Note that the inclusion/exclusion mechanism works on the fully qualified name of the classes, *not* the directory structure; so you can't exclude `src/main/java`.

Assuming all of your main java source files are under the `my.package` package, you can have:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>${java.version}</source>
    <target>${java.version}</target>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution> <!-- this execution excludes my main sources under my.package -->
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration> <!-- no lint check -->
        <excludes>
          <exclude>my/package/**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution> <!-- this execution includes my main sources under my.package -->
      <id>compile-main</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration> <!-- adds lint check -->
        <includes>
          <include>my/package/**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <compilerArgs>
          <arg>-Xlint:all,-rawtypes</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works because the first execution overrides the `default-compile` execution that Maven launches automatically on the `compile` phase, so it makes sure that the generated classes are compiled first.

#### Using two modules

As such, you need to split this in 2 modules, where the first module would generate the sources and compile them, while the second module would depend on the first one. Create a [multi-module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and have a parent `my-parent` [with 2 modules](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>my-generating-module</module>
    <module>my-module</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

You could add a [`<pluginManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) block here to define default configuration for all the modules using it, like `<source>` and `<target>`.

The first module, `my-generating-module`, is responsible for generating and compiling the sources without any lint check. By default, [`showWarnings`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showWarnings) is `false` so you can keep the default configuration.

Then, in the second module, you can have a dependency on this first one, adding the lint check. Since this will only compile your project sources (the classes generated were already compiled and packaged in the other module), you won't have any warnings for those.

Comment: This is a smart solutions, Thanks! However, it adds a lot of extra complexity to the build. Not sure if this is acceptable. Should check what the possibilities are with Gradle :)

Comment: @rmuller I thought of another possible solution and edited with that.

Comment: I would prefer the two-module approach. Having two compiler plugin executions for a single maven module is very unintuitive.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Yes, agree, I'd prefer it as well.

Comment: Include/exclude does not work in our use-case, because the generated sources are in "our" package name. So I need to exclude/include the 'target/generated-source' directory. I cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker You are right, that is the more elegant approach. But it adds extra complexity.

Comment: @rmuller That's the issue, you won't be able to do that... Classes are excluded with regard to their package declaration. Might still be a viable alternative for other people so worth mentioning.

Comment: @Tunaki. Yes that is a good addition indeed and makes your answer great for referencing.

Comment: How to do it when the two "modules" are dependent on each other? We have sources generated by antlr which use our own classes - and then our classes use the antlr generated parsers. Antlr generated code fires lot of lint warnings, but we still want to use lint for our code.