# Ant: Exclude generated sources from -Xlint check

Tags: java, ant, lint

We are using `-Xlint:all` together with `-Werror` in our project. We have a parser based on ANTLR2 and the code generated from antlr is not nice and fires lot of lint warnings. Thus we need to disable lint check for the generated sources.

The problem is, that the generated sources depend on our sources (ANTRL allows to use custom AST nodes, for example) and our sources of course depend on ANTLR sources (i.e. we use the generated parsers).

Is it possible to exclude sources from lint check, but still compile it together?

(See slightly related [Maven 3: How to exclude generated sources from Xlint check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994647/maven-3-how-to-exclude-generated-sources-from-xlint-check))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution.

```
target name="compile" depends="antlr">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>

    <!-- compile antlr generated sources -->
    <!-- compiles also necessary sources from sourcepath -->
    <javac srcdir="build/antlr" destdir="build/classes" sourcepath="src" classpath="ext/antlr.jar>
    </javac>

    <!-- compile sources -->
    <!-- already prebuilt antlr classes are present -->
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" classpath="ext/antlr.jar">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:all"/>
        <compilerarg value="-Werror"/>
        <!-- needed to recompile already compiled sources with lint enabled -->
        <compilerarg value="-Xprefer:source"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

The first `javac` compiles only antlr generated sources and all necessary sources which the antlr generated code depends on.
The second `javac` compiles all non-generated sources with `-Xlint:all` and `-Werror` and reuse pre-built classes from antlr generated code. Note the `-Xprefer:source` which forces `javac` to recompile all non-generated sources even if there is already the corresponding `.class` file from the first step.